# DropBox: Form submit file directly to DropBox

Tags: file, dropbox

I was looking for a way to submit a file directly to DrobBox from a simple form passing the oauth but I  did not find anything so I am almost convinced that I will have to send the file to my server and then send it to dropbox.

Anyone knows if there is a way to submit a file directly to DrobBox from a simple form, actually is there a service in dropbox which accepts it?

THks

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you should use the official Dropbox API which you can find here https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: I already read the api and I am talking with dropbox using ruby. I guess It is not possible to send a file directly from my form, sure maybe using an iframe to post to dropbox but how will I get the datafile?

Comment: There is a dropbox API for Ruby here https://github.com/riscfuture/dropbox  
does that not do what you need, if not I think you need to explain more.....

Comment: I am using that api, it works fine but I want a service like as3 does: http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html to post a file directly to dropbox without touch in my server.